# New Relic Platform plugins and RVM

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

New Relic: some of your plugins need Ruby and your code uses system Ruby. Could you add version (or examples) for users using RVM?

p.s. New Relic Platform is a great move, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

New Relic has provided the platform on which plugins are built. Most plugins have been created by the community and support for plugins is provided by their authors.

Each plugin author has a support link where you can contact them for help getting your plugin installed and configured. https://newrelic.com/docs/plugins/getting-plugin-help

Each plugin is unique and how tools like RVM should be used with any specific plugin may also be unique. The plugin publisher will always have the best answer to question like this.